# iOS Percentage Keeps Rounding

Tags: ios, percentage, nsinteger

I am trying to get an exact percentage for certain parts of my app to two decimal places (73.38%), but no matter what I do, it rounds it to (73.00%).  What is going on with this code?

```
NSInteger acceptedCount = objects.count;
NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)acceptedCount];
needvisiting.text = [inStr stringByAppendingString:@" Need Visiting"];
float precentage = (100 * acceptedCount)/self.homesVisited;
VisitedPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f%%",precentage];
```

Comment: Did you try to set up a breakpoint and inspect the value of each variable on the debugger?

Comment: I inspected it all, acceptedCount is 19, and self.homesVisited is 98, but percentage comes out to 19.00%

Comment: Change 100 to 100.0

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy that was it.

Comment: My guess is self.homesVisited is an integer or initialized as integer. It must be a float. 12 = integer. Float always have decimal point. So 12 as float must be written as 12.0.

Comment: @user717452 Be sure to read the linked question and its answers you understand why that change was needed.